# Creating tables in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, css-tables

I am trying to create tables using the div tag in Visual Studio 2013 but the problem is that in design view I keep having the columns underneath each other instead of being on the same row.

Here is my code:

```
            <div id="TM">
               <div class="row" style="background-color:orange">
                   <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:blueviolet">
                      <label>Supplier</label>
                   </div>

                   <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:pink" role="textbox"></div>
                   <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:blueviolet">
                      <label>Estimated Budget</label>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:pink">
                      <div class="Textbox" style="height:20px; width:50px" role="textbox"></div>
              </div>                            
           </div>
```

Comment: I think you need horizontal view of DIV?

Comment: You're missing a `</div>` tag at the end there - your `<div id="TM">` isn't being closed. (I'm going to assume this is a typo and not contributing to the actual issue).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4966/ increase the output window width if it is showing the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why exactly you want to force divs to display tabular data? It's a very bad practice and you really shouldn't do that. Don't underestimate semantics. Every time you have a tabular data, you should use `<table>`.

Tag `<table>` should be avoided only when you use it for defining website layout, because it leads to problematic scenarios and a really clunky design. In a scenario like this however, when you obviously use tabular data and try to reinvent the wheel by forcing divs to do table design, `<table>` is a really way to go.

Few more notes:

- wysiwyg editor in Visual studio is suitable really just for fast prototyping, but shouldn't be used for actual laying out the web application. Write the html by hand
- try to avoid inline styles. use external css files whenever possible, unless you want to run into numerous problems in the future. Your current code will be a nightmare to maintain..

Comment: i will be placing all the css in an external file but i am currently testing something. well i am using divs cause i am using bootstrap and my professor asked us to use the div tags instead so i am forced to use divs. you would really save me if you can solve this problem for me. Thank you in advance

Comment: @SurayaNasser, I rather won't comment on your professor... However, does the problem occur only in the editor? Or have you tried it in the browser as well?

Comment: well i tried to view it in browser but there was another issue with the browser linking so thats why i couldnt decide if the problem is with visual studio only

Comment: @SurayaNasser, well, I'm asking because the editor is kinda buggy and you can't really rely on it's functionality to be honest... It's great for windows/phone development, but I never made it to work properly for production websites...

Comment: so would it be a good idea to give him the code while trusting that what i wrote is right? or should i try to fix the linking issue to test?

Comment: @SurayaNasser, fix the issue and work with the real browser. Just don't forget that every browser can display your website a little differently, so check with multiple browsers (at least with 2, so Internet Explorer + some other).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp in order to display div as if they are a tablet you have to get the structure of your html and css correct, with float lefts in the correct position. Given your code above, the below should work. Note in production code you really should re-factor the "Style" elements into a CSS stylesheet as much as is possible.

```
    <div id="TM">
           <div class="row" style="background-color:orange">
               <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:blueviolet; float:left;">
                  <label>Supplier</label>
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:pink; float:left;" role="textbox"></div>
               <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:blueviolet; float:left;">
                  <label>Estimated Budget</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:pink; float:left;">
               <div class="Textbox" style="height:20px; width:50px; float:left;" role="textbox"></div>
          </div>
       </div>
```